# Creating Customised button on silverlight for windows phone c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, expression-blend

Hello everyone i would like to create a customised button which looks like a chat dialog shape instead of the normal rectangle . May i know how would i be able to do so?

I tried expression blend but it didnt work out well, read about it and found out that its more like creating a library for it so i can import the work.

Would be nice if someone could show me some tutorials on how it can be done using either the current VS or expression blend which most likey is the case,

THanks in advance!

Regards,
TransformBinary
                                                                                                                 
Hi guys, sry that i missed this point out, its a code generated button

Meaning i'm trying to
`MyButton btn = new MyButton();`
instead of
`Button btn = new Button();`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613598.aspx) or [this one](http://expressioniq.com/?p=2116). It's about WPF but in Silverlight things will be absolutely the same. Google may give tons of such tutorials, e.g. search by "button template blend wpf".

Comment: HMm more like, What about creating a customized button and importing it into visual studio silverlight project

Answer (score 0):

I created a user control from visual studio and right click then brought it over to Expression blend I manage to create the customized button but i add a event handler to it, i cant Btn.Click :\

```
  <UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:edc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Drawing"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="Volunteer.LayoutRootControl" Height="127" Width="200">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle8" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <edc:Callout AnchorPoint="0.85,1.19" CalloutStyle="Rectangle" Fill="#FFE054EF" FontSize="14.666999816894531" Stroke="Black"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Height="96" Width="196"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle8}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="102" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="197" Margin="-40,-34,-41,-32">
                <TextBlock Width="196" x:Name="BtnIN3" Text="" FontSize="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,-12" Height="95" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I cant give it a event handler even by typing b2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(BtnChiefAns);